# Shiny App Partially Printing Function Output

Tags: r, shiny

I have a very simple test script (`Test.R`) saved in a shared drive (`K:\\Market Risk\\R\\Scripts\\`) that I would like to call from a Shiny app.

```
rm(list=ls())
Sys.sleep(5)
```

Within my app, I've written a function to call the script and show the app user whether or not the function is running; which runs as expected on it's own.

```
run_test <- function() {
  print("Running...")
  source("K:\\Market Risk\\R\\Scripts\\Test.R", local = T)
  print("Complete")
}
```

However, when deployed on my app, the text output only shows "Complete" once it finishes running and "Running..." is only displayed in my console and not the app.

```
library(shiny)

run_test <- function() {
  print("Running...")
  source("K:\\Market Risk\\R\\Scripts\\Test.R", local = T)
  print("Complete")
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  tabsetPanel(
    tabPanel("Reporting",
             br(),
             verticalLayout(
               fluidRow(strong("Test"), 
                        actionButton("Run_Test", "Run"), 
                        textOutput("text")
                        )
               )
             )
    )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  observeEvent(input$Run_Test, {
    output$text <- renderText(run_test())
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Has anyone experienced this before?

Comment: [`print`'s docs](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.1/topics/print) start out with: *"prints its argument and returns it **invisibly**"*. So the one you see is the one that's being returned from the function. `print` is never going to add something mid-step to an HTML object. There are techniques using `withCallingHandlers` and `message` to gather mid-call *messages* and use them in a shiny interface, but they are not trivial (and I don't have the link handy).

Comment: @r2evans Thanks for the info, I'll try digging into using `withCallingHandlers` and `message` and report back.

Comment: See https://deanattali.com/blog/advanced-shiny-tips/#show-warnings-messages

Comment: @r2evans Thank you! From that link I was able to find the code doing exactly what I need here: https://github.com/daattali/advanced-shiny/blob/master/show-warnings-messages/app.R

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @r2evans I was able to find example code doing exactly what I need here: https://github.com/daattali/advanced-shiny/blob/master/show-warnings-messages/app.R